# Blank page with setTimeZone displayed before page load

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I've created a page that automatically logs a user into my apex application from another page using the login credentials from that page.

Everything works fine, except for a few seconds while the pl/sql code is 
running, a blank page with 'setTimezone' link is displayed.

[setTimezone link that is displayed for 1-2 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9rPr.png)

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: could you post the page url in that moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set Automatic Time Zone to Yes, look at following image and set this to No After No such screen Appear:

[image: image of Set Auto Time zone to No]